# Could not cast value of type UIViewController to Test.PagingMenuController in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to use [this control](https://github.com/kitasuke/PagingMenuController) in my test project:

I get this error : "Could not cast value of type UIViewController to Test.PagingMenuController"
In the example it works fine. but in my test project I get error on this line:

```
let pagingMenuController = self.childViewControllers.first as! PagingMenuController
```

in front of this line I see this message too:
'Thread 1: SIGABRT'

how can I fix this?

## 1 Edit:

here's the whole code of viewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, PagingMenuControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        let firstViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FirstViewController") as! FirstViewController
        let newsViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("NewsTableViewController") as! NewsTableViewController
        let thirdViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ThirdViewController") as! ThirdViewController
        let fourthViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("FourthViewController") as! FourthViewController
        
        let viewControllers = [firstViewController, newsViewController, thirdViewController, fourthViewController]
        
        let options = PagingMenuOptions()
        options.menuHeight = 50
        
        let pagingMenuController = self.childViewControllers.first as! PagingMenuController
        pagingMenuController.delegate = self
        pagingMenuController.setup(viewControllers: viewControllers, options: options)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - PagingMenuControllerDelegate
    
    func willMoveToMenuPage(page: Int) {
    }
    
    func didMoveToMenuPage(page: Int) {
    }
}
```

Comment: We're going to need to see a lot more code than this.

Comment: I'm not at all sure of this but the "Test." part might be a clue.  Is `PagingMenuController` being built as a separate module?

Comment: @PhillipMills the project name is Test. so the class inside Test is Test.className. PagingMenuController has 4 classes which I have added to my project manually. couldn't use its POD so I added the files manually